# How to be able to open the file explorer in a class component and read the selected file in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to open the file explorer based on a props condition.
However, due to a class Component I am not able use the useEffect hook.

Below is my code :

The class component :

```
class UploadFile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
           isClicked:0
      };
      this.inputFileRef = React.createRef();
      this.onFileExplorerClick = this.onFileExplorerClick.bind(this);
    }

    onFileExplorerClick(fileRef) {
      this.setState ({isClicked:1});
      fileRef.current.click();
   }

   clickMe() {
    console.log("this is click Me!");
   }

   render() {
    const loadFile = this.props.loadFile;
    return (
       <div>
          <Button onClick= {()=>this.clickMe()}>Click this </Button>
          { (loadFile && 
            <form style={{ visibility: "collapse" }}>
            <input type="file" ref={this.inputFileRef} />
            <button onClick={this.onFileExplorerClick(this.inputFileRef)}></button>
            </form>

          ) || ''}

       </div>


    ); 
 }

}
```

If I am using a function component with useEffect the file explorer is popping up and working, but in class component , I am not able to bring it up and access the file uploaded.

The inputFileRef inside the onFileExplorer click is coming as undefined(or null), hence the click event `(this.inpuFileRef.current.click())` is not happening. How can it be captured without actually clicking on a visible Choose File button ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the render function and added life Cycle methods which could solve it.

```
class UploadFile extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
           isClicked:0
      };
      this.inputFileRef = React.createRef();
      this.onFileExplorerClick = this.onFileExplorerClick.bind(this);
    }


   componentDidMount() {

     let loadFile =  this.props.loadFile;
     if(loadFile) this.setState ({isClicked:1});
     }
     componentDidUpdate() {
      if(this.state.isClicked) this.onFileExplorerClick();
     }

    onFileExplorerClick() {
      this.inputFileRef.current.click();
      this.setState ({isClicked:0});
   }

   clickMe() {
    console.log("this is click Me!");
   }

   render() {
    const loadFile = this.props.loadFile;
    return (
       <div>
          <Button onClick= {()=>this.clickMe()}>Click this </Button>
          <input type="file" ref={this.inputFileRef} style:{{visibility:"collapse"}} />
            
       </div>


    ); 
 }

}
```